# when I create table, I got this error ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

When I create the table, I got this error `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier`, I don't know what the error means.

```
Create table c_stock(s_date date not null,
                     o_stock number(4),
                     add number(4),
                     total number(4));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's working perfectly fine

Comment: Look at syntax highlighting **`add`** keyword is **BLUE**

Answer (score 5):

From the [ORA-00904 description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm):

> **ORA-00904 string: invalid identifier**
>
> Cause: **The column name entered is either missing or invalid**.
>
> Action: Enter a valid column name. A valid column name must begin with
>   a letter,be less than or equal to 30 characters, and consist of only
>   alphanumeric characters and the special characters $, _, and #. If it
>   contains other characters, then it must be enclosed in double
>   quotation marks. It may not be a **reserved word**.

Looking at the [list of Oracle reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm), **`ADD`** appears on the second row.

Changing that column name should resolve your problem.